# How can I handle number of pages to appear before the current page in the pagination?

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my code:

```
// current page
$p = $_GET['page'];

// the number of all pages
$page_nums = 5;

// pagination should be created
if( $page_nums > 1 ) {
    $data['pagination'] = '<div class="pagination_box">';

    // backward btn
    if ($p > 1) {
        $data['pagination'] .= "<a class='pagination_backward' href=''>قبلی</a>";
        $data['pagination'] .= '<span style="color:#848d95; margin:0px 10px;">…</span>';
    } 

    $pagination_active = "pagination_active";
    for($i = $p; $i <= $page_nums; $i++){
        $data['pagination'] .= "<a class='$pagination_active' href=''>$i</a> ";
        $pagination_active = '';
        if ($i >= 2 && $i % 2) {
           $data['pagination'] .= '<span style="color:#848d95; margin:0px 10px;">…</span>';
           $data['pagination'] .= "<a href=''>$page_nums</a>";
           break;
        }
    }

    // forward btn
    $data['pagination'] .= ($page_nums > $p) ? '<a class="pagination_backward" href="">بعدی</a>' : null;
```

The result of it doesn't look good all the times. Here are some examples:

`$_GET['page'] = 0;`

[image]

`$_GET['page'] = 1;`

[image]

`$_GET['page'] = 4;`

[image]

---

As you see, the first example looks good.

The second one is not bad *(it would be better if the number of page `1` been visible instead of `...`)*

The third one is awful. It's totally wrong.

I really don't know how can I fix the problem. Do you have any idea?

**Noted:** the language I use is **right-to-left** and `قبلی` means `prev`, and `بعدی` means `next`.

Comment: So you've said what's good, not bad and awful. What are you actually trying to achieve? E.g. How many links before `...` and after, etc.

Comment: @fubar I don't care ... 2 or 3 links before `...` would be fine ..

Comment: In that case, you need to look at your `for` loop. It only produces links for after the current page. It doesn't take into account links before the current page.

Comment: yes I know .. I'm working on that

Comment: Okay, so create a second `for` loop. One to handle links before the current page, and one to handle links after. Or modify your current loop to not start at the current page.

Comment: I'm trying  . . . `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care how many links show before/after the current page, you could use the following:

```
// Prepare current, total pages and pagination container
$current = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
$total = 5;
$pagination = [];

// Check if pagination required
if ($total > 1) {
    // Check if current page is not first page
    if ($current > 1) {
        $pagination[] = '<a class="pagination_backward" href="#">قبلی</a>';
        $pagination[] = '<span style="color:#848d95; margin:0px 10px;">…</span>';
    }

    // Iterate through pages
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
        // Check if handling current page
        if ($i === $current) {
            $pagination[] = '<a class="pagination_active" href="#">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
        else {
            $pagination[] = '<a href="#">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
    }

    // Check if current page is not last page
    if ($current < $total) {
        $pagination[] = '<span style="color:#848d95; margin:0px 10px;">…</span>';
        $pagination[] = '<a class="pagination_backward" href="#">بعدی</a>';
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($pagination);
echo '</pre>';
// $pagination = implode('', $pagination);
```

**Edit**

And if you do care how many adjacent links show before / after the current page, you could use the following, changing `$adjacent` accordingly.

```
// Prepare current, total and adjacent pages and pagination container
$current = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
$total = 5;
$adjacent = 2;
$pagination = [];

// Check if pagination required
if ($total > 1) {
    // Check if current page is not first page
    if ($current > 1) {
        $pagination[] = '<a class="pagination_backward" href="#">قبلی</a>';
        $pagination[] = '<span style="color:#848d95; margin:0px 10px;">…</span>';
    }

    // Prepare adjacent page delimiters
    $min = max(1, $current - $adjacent);
    $max = min($current + $adjacent, $total);

    // Iterate through pages
    for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        // Check if handling current page
        if ($i === $current) {
            $pagination[] = '<a class="pagination_active" href="#">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
        else {
            $pagination[] = '<a href="#">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
    }

    // Check if current page is not last page
    if ($current < $total) {
        $pagination[] = '<span style="color:#848d95; margin:0px 10px;">…</span>';
        $pagination[] = '<a class="pagination_backward" href="#">بعدی</a>';
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($pagination);
echo '</pre>';
// $pagination = implode('', $pagination);
```

Comment: thanks, upvote. But in the your first version, there is `...` between the last link and `next` button. I guess it doesn't seem good. https://3v4l.org/JPC7Q

Comment: I just took that from your code where you're adding the ... automatically. That's why I was asking you to clarify exactly what it was you wanted...